# The secret Santa present-swapping paradox

Tags: secondary-education

[*This may be the wrong SE for this question. But as a non-mathematician I feel it may be too simple for MathOverflow, and that I might benefit from a school-level explanation. Also, it might make a fun seasonal class assignment.*]

If everyone in a classroom is involved in a Secret Santa style present exchange then, intuitively, it seems to make sense that it requires an even number in order to be fair. Someone gives a present, another receives: that's a pair. If there's an odd number in the class, someone will lose out.

Except they won't. Let there be three people in the class: pupils A, B and C. A gives to B, B gives to C, C gives to A.

In terms of "common sense" thinking this appears to be a paradox. Obviously it isn't. Can someone explain why not, mathematical terms?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier for students to understand if the situation was drawn as a directed graph?  Model each student as a vertex, an arrow from a vertex to a different vertex represents the giving and receiving of a present, and each vertex should have exactly two edges (one incoming, the other outgoing).

Comment: This is *definitely* not appropriate for MathOverflow (which is for research mathematics). In general if you have a simpler maths question you should go to Math.SE. As it is, I can't work out whether you are asking for the answer or for how to explain the answer.

Comment: It is *sufficient* to group people in pairs to organize a Secret Santa exchange, but not *necessary*.  I am not sure what further explanation you want besides a counterexample.  It is not a paradox, but a mistaken understanding of what is required to organize a Secret Santa exchange.

Comment: "...intuitively, it seems to make sense that it requires an even number in order to be fair." An even number of *what*? If you mean people, then you have indicated why this needn't be the case. But I wonder whether you are, perhaps, getting muddled up in computing the total number of actions (viz., the actions of giving and receiving); indeed, in your example of A to B to C to A, the number of actions is 3 giving + 3 receiving = 6 actions, which is even.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If someone gives a present and another receives it, they are indeed a pair.  If there are n pairs, it would seem there are 2n students.  The problem with that is the pairs overlap and every student is in two pairs.

This is shown in your counterexample.  A gives to B, B gives to C, and C gives to A.  There are 3 pairs and 3 students.  The can be generalized to n pairs and n students. For example if there are 5 students: A gives to B, B gives to C, and C gives to D, D gives to E and E gives to A.

IF n is odd, the number of pairs will be odd. Thus there can be an odd number of students and an odd number of pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the word "Secret" in "Secret Santa": The recipient is not supposed to know who his or her Santa is. If presents were *swapped* then the receiver of my present would be presenting the present for me, so I would know who my Secret Santa is and so would they.

That's why the receivers are a permutation of the givers, with no fixed point (because nobody should buy their own present), and nobody being told that they are part of a cycle of length 2.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically you are looking at a bijection G (for Giving) with no fixed point, on a finite set S with at least 2 members, and its inverse bijection R (for Receiving). When S has at least 3 members it is not inevitable that a "gift-pair"  exists. A gift-pair is a pair (x,y) of members of S for which G(x)=y and G(y)=x.(Or equivalently R(x)=y and R(y)=x.) And if S has an odd number of members, at least  3 them do not belong to any gift-pairs.